# Dictionary with list remove u ticks and brackets

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I'm having an issue accessing a list within a dictionay in ansible.
It's actually more complex than this, I've made a simplified version of the issue for brevity.

ansible version is 2.9

The dictionary looks like:

```yaml
data_dict:
  data:
    arch_paths:
    - /opt/data1/20201007_test1
    - /opt/data1/20201013_test2
    - /opt/data1/20201029_test3
    bucket: host-data
    path: archives/host
    src_path: /opt/data1
  targz:
    arch_paths:
    - /opt/data2/20201005.tar.gz
    - /opt/data2/20201013.tar.gz
    - /opt/data2/20201029.tar.gz
    bucket: app-data
    path: archives/app
    src_path: /opt/data2
```

My task examples:

```yaml
- name: print files to archive
  debug:
    msg: "{{item.value.arch_paths}}"
  loop: "{{ data_dict|dict2items }}"

- name: Archive the things
  shell: echo "{{item.value.bucket}} -k {{item.value.path}} -p {{item.value.src_path}} {{item.value.arch_paths}}" >> /var/log/put.log
  loop: "{{ data_dict|dict2items }}"
```

These run as expected. But, what ends up in the log file is:

```
host-data -k archives/host -p /opt/data1 [u'/opt/data1/20201007_test1', u'/opt/data1/20201013_test2', u'/opt/data1/20201029_test3']
app-data -k archives/app -p /opt/data2 [u'/opt/data2/20201005.tar.gz', u'/opt/data2/20201013.tar.gz', u'/opt/data2/20201029.tar.gz']
```

I want to remove the `u'...'` and commas so I just have the values with spaces e.g.

```
host-data -k archives/host -p /opt/data1 /opt/data1/20201007_test1 /opt/data1/20201013_test2 /opt/data1/20201029_test3 
app-data -k archives/app -p /opt/data2 /opt/data2/20201005.tar.gz /opt/data2/20201013.tar.gz /opt/data2/20201029.tar.gz
```

I've seen similar problems on this site but have been unable to adapt any of the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `arch_paths` is a list, so, you just need to [`join`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#join) the list items: `item.value.arch_paths | join(' ')`.

With the task:

```yaml
- shell: echo "{{ item.value.bucket }} -k {{ item.value.path }} -p {{ item.value.src_path }} {{ item.value.arch_paths | join(' ') }}" >> /var/log/put.log
  loop: "{{ data_dict|dict2items }}"
```

It gives a file */var/log/put.log* containing:

```
host-data -k archives/host -p /opt/data1 /opt/data1/20201007_test1 /opt/data1/20201013_test2 /opt/data1/20201029_test3
app-data -k archives/app -p /opt/data2 /opt/data2/20201005.tar.gz /opt/data2/20201013.tar.gz /opt/data2/20201029.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks! (I KNEW it was simple) ;-)